# React redux -how to get data in each components after the api response written in Reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

am new to redux and react.

I have just gone through some redux tutorial and started to implement some sue cases .. And one use case i really want is i need a state that i should get in all components,so thats possible with redux as globalized state.

I have a scenario,an api call and i should get this api response in all my components using redux. But thats not happening.

I have index.js as

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import allReducer from "./reducers";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

import "./styles.css";


let store = createStore(
  allReducer,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);
```

My reducer as

```
var userArray = [];
fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(
    result => {
      console.log(result);
      userArray = result;
    },

    error => {}
  );

const IsLoggedReducer = (state, action) => {
  console.log(userArray);
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SIGNIN":
      return (state = userArray);
    case "LOGGEDOUT":
      return (state = userArray);
    default:
      return (state = userArray);
  }
};
export default IsLoggedReducer;
```

and my app.js as

```
import React from "react";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

function App() {
  const counter1 = useSelector(state => state.counterReducer);
  const isLogged = useSelector(state => state.IsLoggedReducer);

  return (
    <h1>
      This {counter1}
      <ul>
        {isLogged.length > 0
          ? isLogged.map(item => {
              return <li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>;
            })
          : "No data"}
      </ul>
    </h1>
  );
}

export default App;
```

when initial load its coming as null array and when i make some edit t the component and save ,it gets data and gets populated..

Here is the code https://codesandbox.io/embed/quirky-sunset-s95gu?fontsize=14

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: First of all, don't call APIs or functions inside the reducers. Use actions for that purpose then call the reducers using types

Comment: @Yahiya .. Can you tell,how i can call the same in actions

Comment: I suggest one more tutorial for you. As you are handling async request in your actions, I suggest to use redux-thunk (or redux-saga, but redux-thunk is simplier for beginners) -  https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk#why-do-i-need-this

Answer (score 1):

I hope this simple codes for action and reducer can help you understand react-redux.

For `action`,

```
export const signin = (userArray) => {
  return {
    type: "SIGNIN",
    payload: userArray,
  };
};

export const loggedout = (userArray = []) => {
  // You can do something for making users logged out here using userArray and return changed value using payload
  // Or just return [] as payload because it's logged out
  return {
    type: "LOGGEDOUT"
    payload: userArray,
  };
};

export const initiate = (userArray) => {
  return {
    type: "INITIATE",
    payload: userArray,
  }
}
```

For `reducer`, please consider reducer as changer of state.

```
const IsLoggedReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SIGNIN":
      return action.payload;
    case "LOGGEDOUT":
      return action.payload;
    case "INITIATE":
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

When it comes to calling api, I want to recommend to use `redux-saga` or `redux-thunk` but if you need calling api just one time at the beginning of the component. You may be able to use `useEffect`(https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) as `componentDidMount` is used for calling api in a class component.

And I hope this useEffect code can help you get the feeling

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { initiate } from 'actions';

function main () {
  const state = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const onInit = useCallback((data) => dispatch(initiate(data), [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // call api and get response
    const userArray = fetch();

    onInit(userArray);
  }, []);

  return (<div>...</div>);
}
```

Comment: I did like that,but how we will call in component ?

Comment: If you use the `class` component, you would be able to call fetch in `componentDidMount`. Then, you can save results which are from api by calling the action that is responsible for initialising userArray. That action would be named "INITIATE".

Comment: its possible with ComponentDidMount ,but again for getting in different components it need to passed as props ,thats again burder,i need something using redux and get it in all components

Comment: Please check the answer that I've edited. Once you save data using `OnInit` in redux store, you can get it through all components using `useSelector`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you are not doing some things in a right way

1 - As API calling is an asynchronous task so you need to handle it, I would recommend write some action creator which does this API calling for you, and when you get the response from API then dispatch appropriate action to update the store state.

2- In your reducer you are mutating the state, don't  mutate the previous state, instead return new state object from previous state

Hope it helps

Comment: @ ibtsam -Thanks for the reply .Can you help me to in codesandbox,i had shared the code url
https://codesandbox.io/embed/quirky-sunset-s95gu?fontsize=14